# Spring boot security get username and password from authentication login to access rest services

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring. Client requests to access the rest services, giving username and password in http login provided by Spring, as shown in the image. I don't want to save credentials('username and password') in the application.properties. When I provide the credentials and enter login button, I need to read data (in my case username-'root' and pwd-'root') provided by the user from login and use it in my algorithm, do the process and then authenticate. Is there a way?

Please help me, if anyone has any idea.

[authentication login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nwh0.png) 
Here is my sample code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("user1Pass").roles("ADMIN")
    // .and().withUser("user2").password("user2Pass").roles("ADMIN");

    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

}

public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    // provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return provider;

}

// I am trying like this but not sure is this the right way
public void details(User user) {
    String name = user.getName();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    System.out.println("name " + name + "password" + password);
}
// I am trying like this but not sure is this the right way
public void userDetails(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter) {
    String usernameParameter = filter.getUsernameParameter();
    System.out.println(usernameParameter);
    String passwordParameter = filter.getPasswordParameter();
    System.out.println(passwordParameter);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

}

}


@Component
public class MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends 
BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint{

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, 
ServletException {

    response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm="  +  
    getRealmName());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    PrintWriter printWriter= response.getWriter();
    printWriter.println("Http Status 401-" + authException.getMessage());
}

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    //RealName appears in the login window
    setRealmName("Rashmi");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
  }
}



@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRestfulWebServiceApplication extends 
SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    CustomerDetailsController customerDetailsController;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(SpringRestfulWebServiceApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
    application) {
      return application.sources(SpringRestfulWebServiceApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Comment: Thanks for the link :) I want to get the username and password entered by the user. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the user entered values of username and password in a spring security authenticated login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931606/how-to-get-the-user-entered-values-of-username-and-password-in-a-spring-security)

Comment: I had a look on this but this is not what i need. I will try to explain it better  Give me few minutes.

Comment: @MarcTarin it is not duplicate as far I understand. I am looking for different solution. I have edited my question.

Comment: @R12 Can post your sample code how trying to access the user name password?

Comment: @DipakThoke I have posted my sample code. when the user enters login button, the credentials entered in the username and password textfield on the authentication login popup provided by spring security need to retrieved. I am completely new to Spring not able to find a proper solution.

Comment: You have login method right?

Comment: In your login contorller

Comment: I don't have login controller, because just by including dependency will get a login popup from spring.